# Angular2: How to modify Form Control's input value before putting in data model

Tags: angular

I have a form model with:

`form = new FormGroup({currency: new FormControl('')})`

Entering values in the control has masking characters enabled:

`$ 123, 456`

Now how do I make my `form.value` to return `{ currency: 123456 }`?

I tried `this.form.controls['currency'].setValue(123456)` but doesn't work.

Comment: How do you mask the value ? Because as soon as you use setValue , the value will be masked again right ?

Comment: I'm using the [text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask) library. It worked with `controlValueAccessor` on `ngModel`- i removes the mask characters in the `ngModelChange`. But no idea how to achieve the same thing with reactive forms..

Comment: You can also use `ngModelChange` with reactive forms

Comment: Just found this 
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(obj => obj.field = obj.field.replace(/\D+/g, ''));

Comment: Scroll to the bottom https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/issues/109

Comment: @yurzui Would you show a quick example how to use `ngModelChange` on reactive forms?

@Milad Thanks that works. I tried similar thing `this.form.value['currency'] = '123456'` but didn't work. Weird. But looks like this works only with `form.value` not `form.getRawValue()` cuz I need to get the `disabled` fields too

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/dlzKAsmo3SLAl7DkCA7I?p=preview Type something and observe console

Answer (score -1):

You can do using directive ngModel.$parsers.push and ngModel.$formatters.push

```
'use strict'
// Directive to show the browser sepcific decimal separator for Numeric 
controls.
angularPracticeApp.directive('apNumberInput', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^ngModel',
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

        // Runs when the value change from UI.
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
            if (value && typeof (value) === "string")
                return value.replace(',', '.');
            else
                return value;
        });

        // Runs when the value change from code.
        ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
            if (value && typeof (value) === "string")
                return value.replace('.', ',');
            else
                return value;
        });
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I guess the question is about angular2